# PHP Array for HTML Select Not Allowing Duplicate 'value="

Tags: php, html, forms

I've created a simple PHP Array that I wish to use with a select input on a web form (the select input was previously hardcoded in the HTML). Here's the array:

```
$fruits = array( 
                    'fruit' => 'apple',
                    'fruit' => 'orange',
                    'vegetable' => 'potato'
        );
```

and here's the select input:

```
<label for="Food">Select the Food</label><br>



                <select id="Subdiscipline" name="Subdiscipline">
                        <option value="*">- No Selection - </option>
                        <?php 
                            $output = "";
                            $selected = false;

                        foreach($fruits as $fruit => $value) {

                             $fruit = htmlspecialchars($fruit);

                             $output .= "<option value=\"$fruit\"";

                              if ($fruit == $previousFruitSelection) {
                                  $selected = true;
                                  $output .= " selected";
                              }
                              $output .= ">$value</option>";

                        }
                        echo $output;

                            ?>
                    </select>
```

The problem now that I'm no longer hardcoding the options for the select menu is that the option for 'apple' no longer appears, presumably because you can't have duplicate keys in the array. Is there a way around this to use PHP to create an array that is used to drive the select options but allow for multiple options with the same 'value=fruit'?

Comment: The point of a `key` in an array is to be unique , otherwise this is not a key.Consider having a key named `fruits` which would be an array of itself: 'fruits' => array('orange','apple'),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP array is a simple associative array. It matches keys to values, so you cannot have 2 fruits in the array, as the point of the key is to be unique, to be able to identify a certain element in your array.

There are however multiple ways you can solve this. The easiest that comes to mind is to make 2 arrays, one for your "keys" and one for your "values. So the first array would be fruit, fruit, vegetable, and the second would be apple, orange, potato.

You can also use more sophisticated data structures, but what I would probably do is assigning arrays to be the value. You can do that, array in an array. To check exactly how it is done syntaxwise, check on php.net, more specifically check example #6 on the following link, I believe this might help you out:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Thanks - I've setup 2 arrays:           
            
$foodKeys = array( 'fruit', 'fruit', 'vegetable');
            
            
$foodValues = array( 'apple', 'orange', 'potato');

Struggling to work out syntax to then create the html select menu - can you provide an example please?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to create the two arrays without keys, and iterate through the array by indexing it with numbers. Something like:
$foodkeys = array("fruit", "fruit", "vegetable");
$foodvalues = array("apple", "orange", "potato");
for($i=0; $i<count($foodkeys); $i++)
{
   print($foodkeys[i]);
   print($foodvalues[i]);
}
This prints fruitapplefruitorangevegetablepotato. Of course you can modify it to print anything you want in proper HTML syntax, point is, you can access your data like this. Just make sure you have equal number of keys and values, otherwise strange things can happen

Answer (score 2):

You can use multi-dimensional arrays:

```
    $fruits = array( 
                'fruit' => array ('apple', 'orange')
                'vegetable' => array ('potato')
    );
```

Ofc you have to change the loop and iterate over the inner arrays, too.

`keys` *have* to be unique ;)